# Feature importance using gridsearchcv for logistic regression

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I've trained a logistic regression model like this:

```
reg = LogisticRegression(random_state = 40)
cvreg = GridSearchCV(reg, param_grid={'C':[0.05,0.1,0.5],
                                      'penalty':['none','l1','l2'],
                                      'solver':['saga']},
                     cv = 5)
cvreg.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Now to show the feature's importance I've tried this code, but I don't get the names of the coefficients in the plot:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot

importance = cvreg.best_estimator_.coef_[0]
pyplot.bar([x for x in range(len(importance))], importance)
pyplot.show()
```

[image]

Obviously, the plot isn't very informative. How do I add the names of the coefficients to the x-axis?

The importance of the coeff is:

```
cvreg.best_estimator_.coef_
array([[1.10303023e+00, 7.48816905e-01, 4.27705027e-04, 6.01404570e-01]])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The coefficients correspond to the columns of `X_train`, so pass in the `X_train` names instead of `range(len(importance))`.

Assuming `X_train` is a pandas dataframe:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

features = X_train.columns
importance = cvreg.best_estimator_.coef_[0]

plt.bar(features, importance)
plt.show()
```

Note that if `X_train` is just a numpy array without column names, you will have to define the `features` list based on your own data dictionary.

[image: sample output]